# Where do I put the Angular code in this Mean.js app to make this list sortable?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

Following the advice of @Pavlo to use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable,

I have this repeating list that I want to make sortable.

```
<div ui-sortable ng-model="regions" class="list-group region-list">
    <a data-ng-repeat="region in regions" data-ng-href="#!/regions/{{region._id}}" class="list-group-item">
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading" data-ng-bind="region.name"></h4>
    </a>
</div>
```

Following the advice of @nrodic and added `'ui.sortable'` to config.js.

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.sortable'];
```

However, when I add that I get the following message:

**"ui.sortable: jQuery should be included before AngularJS!"**

Any *further* help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, you'll need 'sortable' directive, e.g.: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/src/sortable.js

Comment: @Pavlo, Thanks!  That looks like exactly what I need!  I added "angular-ui-sortable": "~0.12.10" to bower.json.  I ran bower install angular-ui-sortable and I now see it in the public lib folder. I added the path to the sortable.js file in the config\env\all.js file.  But I'm stuck on "Add the sortable module as a dependency to your application module."  Where do I put that line?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your application's modules. To register dependency in main module you can edit `public/config.js` and add `'ui.sortable'` to existing list:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate',
    'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'ui.sortable'];
```

If you are registering your own module and want to enable `ui.sortable` there, then look for file `public/modules/<my-module>/*module.js` and add dependency there:

```
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('<my-module>', ['ui.sortable']);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps.  Thank you!  I am getting closer.  Now I am getting "jQuery should be included before AngularJS".  If I add the jquery path to the all.js file, above the sortable.js file, I get a jQuery error, "Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined".  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Try these steps:

1. bower install jquery --save
2. add 'public/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
       'public/lib/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js,
        in front of angular.js in config\env\all.js
3. add 'ui.sortable' in applicationModuleVendorDependencies located in public/config.js

Following these steps should fix the problem.